# Area of triangle inside parallelogram

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Consider a parallelogram ABCD with centre O and E as the midpoint of side CD.The area of triangle OAE is?
[image]

Ans: ah/8

**My doubt**
I suppose the area of the triangle should be $$\frac{1}{2} × ED × \frac{h}{2}$$. But I am unsure whether the base of the triangle could be taken as ED.
I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174989/height-of-triangle-inside-a-parallelogram).

.
Kindly help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: As you say $\frac{ah}{8}$ looks correct.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MathLover I have added my doubt, please have a look

Comment: What is the area of $\triangle CAE$ with $CE$ as base and height as $h$? And area of $\triangle COE$ is what times the area of $\triangle CAE$?

Comment: I hope you can now see that the area of $\triangle AOE$ is $1/8$ times the area of parallelogram

Comment: or you can directly notice that the area of $\triangle AOE$ is same as $\triangle COE$ which is clearly $1/8$ times the area of parallelogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (1) Extend the line AD in both directions.
- (2) Since AD is parallel to OE, note that the area of $\triangle OEA$ remains constant when A is moved along line AD, so the area $\triangle OEA$ = area $\triangle OED$.
- (3) $\triangle OED$ now has your base ED, and your formula $\frac{1}{2} × ED × \frac{h}{2}$ is correct indeed.
- (3b) the area of $\triangle OED$is $\frac{1}{8}$ times the parallelograms area, again $\frac{ah}{8}$.

Comment: Exactly your point (2) is what I wanted to know how? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: AD is parallel to OE. Any point on AD gives a triangle over base OE with area (OE times its height). This height however is constant for a parallel.